# D3.js Ordinal Scale Axis mis alignment

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis, label, ordinal

I have a simple `d3` bar chart (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/39xdk1x7/5/)). It illustrates a count of scores. Essentially a normal distribution chart. The x axis is an ordinal scale of scores from 0 to 2.

My x axis don't align with the corresponding bars.

If you look at the JS Console while creating a brush extent and clicking on a bar, the selected bar doesn't match the axis label.

The labels seem to be negatively offset from the bars.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function drawChart (data) {
    // Setup Crossfilter dimensions and groups
    var nation      = crossfilter(data),
        byScr       = nation.dimension(function(d){ return d.score; }),
        byScrGrp    = byScr.group().reduceCount(),
        byHosp      = nation.dimension(function(d){ return d.FIPS; }); 

    // Histogram X-Axis ordinal scale
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(0,2,0.1))
            .rangeBands([0, width, 0.5, 0.5 ]);

    var brushScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,2])
            .range([0, width]);

    // Histogram Y-Axis linear scale
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(byScrGrp.all(), function(d){ return d.value; })])
            .range([height/2, 0]);

    // SVG Brush control object
    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
            .x(brushScale)
            .on("brushstart", brushstart)
            .on("brush", brushmove)
            .on("brushend", brushend)

    // Histogram SVG containiner    
    var svg = d3.select("#histogram").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height/2 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Histogram bars
        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(byScrGrp.all())
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d,i){ return i * (width / byScrGrp.size() ); })
            .attr("width", width / byScrGrp.size() - barPadding )
            .attr("y", function(d){ return  y(d.value) ; })
            .attr("height", function(d){ return ((height/2) -y(d.value)); })
            .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.key); })            .on("mouseover", function(d){ d3.select(this).attr("fill", "teal"); console.log(d.key); })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) { d3.select(this).attr("fill", function(d){return color(d.key);}) } );


    // Histogram X Axis Object
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(10);
        // X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .call(xAxis)
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height/2 + ")") ;
        // X Axis Label
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height/2 + margin.bottom) + ")")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("MSPB Score");

    // Histogram Y Axis Object
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(10);
        // Add Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)");
        // Add Y Axis Label
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 0 - 10)
            .attr("x", 0 - (height/4))
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Number of Hospitals");


var brushg = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "brush")
            .call(brush)

    brushg.select('.background')
                .attr('width', width);

    brushg.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("height", height/2);


function brushstart() {
  svg.classed("selecting", true);
}

function brushmove() {
  var s = brush.extent();
  brushg.classed("selected", function(d) { return s[0] <= (d = x(d)) && d <= s[1]; });
}

function brushend() {
         if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .call(brush.extent(brush.extent().map(function(d){return d3.round(d,2); })));

        var extent = brush.extent(); console.log(extent);
}


   }
```

Comment: You might want to make a jsfiddle for this question.

Comment: That is one in the link on first sentence. But I edited to make it a little more obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Edited it a bit more. The way things were, it looked like you might have been linking to a bar chart in general. See if you like it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure out exactly what was going on here but the ugly hack was to manually shift the axis to the left by 35 px.

```
.attr("transform", "translate(-35" + height + ")");
```

Visually, this is passable but doesn't really feel like an explanation of the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue and all this solution doesn't work for me. Just moves the axis around.